# Чтение данных и регистра устройства, подключенного к COM-порту

Tags: python, modbus

Всем привет! Стоит следующая задача. Есть некий прибор, который опрашивает тепловые датчики в режиме реального времени и записывает себе в регистр их показатели. Этот прибор подключен к COM-порту компьютера и общается с ним по Modbus. Нужно написать программу, которая будет считывать данные из регистра устройства и записывать их в файл. Как это лучше реализовать на Питоне? Может кто-то сталкивался с чем-то похожим, знает какую-нибудь библиотеку?
Насколько вообще оптимально писать такие вещи на Питоне? Есть аналогичная программа на C#, но ее код очень тяжело читать и понимать.

Comment: Для работы с СОМ портом можно использовать PySerial   https://gist.github.com/bashkirtsevich/6d037639e8c600b556667558af5b5ba3

Comment: @Виктор
Использую pyserial, имею вот такой код:
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5')
result = ser.read()
print(result)

В ответ программа ничего не выводит, но что-то внутри выполняется, терминал виснет.

Comment: Я не помню точно протокол MODBUS, Используйте, например, ser.read(10) - чтитать 10 байт
Установите timeout для чтения. Перед чтением чего-то из Modbus - туда запрос послать надо https://ipc2u.ru/articles/prostye-resheniya/modbus-rtu/